# How to return a value from a variable based on a condition in another variable within a grouped data frame?

Tags: r

I am calculating some metrics on each of a set of variables within a grouped dataframe using the basic `group_by()` + `summarize_at` approach. Each group represents a small timeseries. One metric I would like to calculate is the initial value (in this case, `day == 1`) of each variable within each group. Thus, the generalized problem is to return a value of a variable based on a criterion in another variable, within groups of a grouped dataframe. Within the `group_by()` + `summarize_at` approach, I believe I need a custom function that `summarize_at` can then apply to each variable. I can successfully deploy other custom functions that depend only on the data variable at hand. I seem to be hung up on getting the function to go look in other columns of the dataframe.

I am not married to this approach, and welcome alternate recommendations. However, I am most comfortable with dplyr.

```
# a dataset
df <- data.frame(day = rep(c(1:5),3),
                 group = c(rep(1,5),rep(2,5),rep(3,5)),
                 var_a = seq(1:15),
                 var_b = seq(2,30, length.out = 15),
                 var_c = seq(3,45, length.out = 15))

# the logic of what I am going for, on a manually extracted example group:
# initial value (day == 1) of var_a for group 2

df_subset <- df %>% 
  filter(group == 2)
df_subset$var_a[which(df_subset$day == 1)]
# [1] 6

# my laughable attempt at a function

initial <- function(x){
  ini <- which(.$day == 1)
  x[ini]
}

# custom function deployed in dplyr pipe (which of course doesn't work)
df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarize_at(c("var_a","var_b","var_c"), 
               list(max = max, ini = initial))
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the `group_by` step, specify the variables to select in `summarise_at` using one of the `select_helpers` (here `starts_with` works fine), and within the `list`, apply the different functions on each of the columns (`~` is one way to prefix the anonymous call instead of explicitly specifying `function(x)`), For the second function, 'day' is not part of the selected columns, but it can be selected with the unquoted column name

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(starts_with('var')),
         list(max = ~max(.), ini = ~ .[day == 1]))
```

Comment: So simple. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Upon adding to my code, I have learned this is not a very robust approach (no fault of @akrun's correct answer). This throws errors if there is not precisely 1 row within each group which meets the criteria. For my purposes, wrapping with mean (`ini = ~mean(.[day == 1])`) was a satisfactory workaround, though it might not be suitable for all similar applications.

Comment: @fantanaman  I would use a `tryCatch` or `possibly` to have an alternative value if there are such exceptions